# Get URL to ajax trough php/sql

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, ajax

Im having some trouble here with a website im trying to renew.
In the head a script is called with the name "jquery.script.js" with some code

```
$.ajax({
            url: 'function.js.php?option=urlget&id='+movie_id,
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(data){
                fanarturl = data['url'];
                alert(fanarturl);
                alert(data.toSource());
                if (data) {
                    $('#background').fadeOut(500, function(){
                        $(this).delay(100).attr('src', 'cache/'+movie_id+'_f.jpg');
                        $(this).fadeIn(500);
                 })
                }
            }
        });
```

So this call's a file with the name "function.js.php".

```
if ($option == 'urlget') {
    require('function.php');

    $fan = get_fanart($mysql_tables, $_GET['id']);
    $fan_js = array(
        'url'    => (isset($fan['url']) ? $fan['url'] : ''),
    );
    echo json_encode($fan_js);
}
```

And this call's a function with is:

```
function get_fanart($mysql_tables, $movie_id) {

        $pos = strrpos($movie_id, "_");
        $MovieID = substr($movie_id, ($pos + 1));

        if(is_numeric($MovieID)){

        $img_sql = 'SELECT id, url FROM ' . $mysql_tables[5]. ' WHERE type="fanart" AND id="'.$MovieID.'"';
        $img_result = @mysql_query($img_sql);
        if ($img_result) {
            $get_img = mysql_fetch_assoc($img_result);
            foreach($get_img as $key => $val) {
                $fanart[$key] = $val;
            }
        }
    return $fanart;
}}
```

The alart of the "jquery.script.js" show's : **({url:""})** 

Now the supid thing is that when I copy the code from "function.js.php" to "index.php"
It show's this: 
**{"url":"http://image.tmdb.org/t/p/original/A82GPC0XeoZMBWDYTe4Dba32cme.jpg"}**

Why is this URL not passed on to the "jquery.script.js" file?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Just a comment about your code. You really should stop using mysql_query, it's deprecated and have a lot of security issue. Consider using PDO or mysqli. Btw, you pass directly the `$_GET['id']` to your function and use it without escaping it. It lets your code open to SQL Injection.

Comment: Also if you are taking `$MovieID` straight from `$_GET` you are open to a SQL injection attack. Use PDO or MySQLI as @RobinCarlier pointed out with [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php).

Comment: Thanks, this is a small website for personal use only, but for safety I added a line in the function "if(is_numeric($MovieID)){"

Answer (score 1):

At the start of function.js.php you've got this:

```
if ($option == 'urlget') {
```

It shouldn't be `$option`, it should be `$_GET['option']`. (Or something like that - my PHP is a little rusty.)

Comment: Hi, i see that the code after the if did execute becauce it show's in the alert ({url:""}), so some information did come back, but just not the URL, also when i drop the function and use "echo '"http.....jpg"' it does work, but just not with the information from the database.

Comment: If you did not declare `$option` somewhere this means that [register globals](http://php.net/manual/en/security.globals.php) is turned on. Register globals "auto-magically" makes global variables for any GET parameter in the request. It is depreciated and A VERY BAD IDEA.

Comment: Huh. I didn't know you could do that. (In my defence it's not how you accessed `id`.) And as papirtiger says, it's a very bad idea.

Comment: +1 Your answer is still totally valid since he doesn´t define `$option` in the question.

Comment: Yes, but as he correctly points out, if it hadn't been set to register globals, it wouldn't have alerted `{url:""}`. I suppose the AJAX call would have failed with a parse error, since the empty string isn't valid JSON.

Answer (score 0):

Admittedly this sort of answer is more suited to codereview.stackexchange.com but your code has tons of ambiguities and a security vulnerability.

```
var promise = $.ajax({
    url: 'function.js.php?option=urlget&id='+movie_id,
    dataType: 'json'
});

// This makes for better readability than a nest of callbacks
promise.done(function(data){    
    console.log(data);
    $('#background').fadeOut(500, function(){
        $(this).delay(100)
               .attr('src', 'cache/'+movie_id+'_f.jpg')
               .fadeIn(500);
    });
});

promise.fail(function(data){
    console.log('oh noes!', data); // @todo what do we do when 'function.js.php' fails?
});
```

`function.js.php`. Notice that we return different HTTP response codes depending on the results.

```
// @todo fill in db credentials
$db = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=test', $user, $pass);

$option = $_GET('option');

if ($option === 'urlget') {
    require('function.php');
    $fan_art = get_fanart($mysql_tables, intval($_GET['id']), $db);

    if  ($fan_art && count($fan_art)) {
        http_response_code(200);
        echo json_encode($fan_art);
    } else if (is_array($fan_art)) {
        http_response_code(404);
        echo json_encode(array('errors' => array('no fan_art found')));
    } else {
        http_response_code(500);
        echo json_encode(array('errors' => array('an error occured when fetching fan art')));
    } 
}
```

`function.php`. Notice that here we pass in the database connection and use bound parameters to insert variables into our SQL.

```
/**
* 
* @param [String] $table - the table to fetch data from
* @param [Int] $movie_id
* @param [PDO] $db - A PDO database connection
* @return [False, Array] Returns false if query fails, otherwise returns array of results
*/
function get_fanart($table, $movie_id, $db) {
    $statement = $db->prepare( "SELECT id, url FROM :table WHERE type = 'fanart' AND id = :id" );
    $sth->bindParam(':table', $table); // default param type is string
    $sth->bindParam(':id', $movie_id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    if ( $sth->execute() ) {
        return $sth->fetchAll(); 
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

On a side comment, your file & variable naming scheme is pretty horrible. Naming a file `.js.php` implies that the PHP file renders javascript. Also naming your files `function` or `functions` is a maintainence nightmare - why not `fan_art.json.php` and `fan_art.php`.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer, i will test and see if this work, the naming is not something i did, i found an opensource website and working to eddit it to what i need, unfortunately im no expert but normaly i can manage this is something out of my knowledge, the naming is not that because there is much more in the files that i pasted here :)